# Redirect traffic to another machine

Tags: networking

I have 3 machines - A, B and C. Can I redirect all Http/Https traffic originating from B and C through A such that the third-party views the the incoming request as sent from A rather than B or C?

Answer (score 0):

For the third party to see the response coming from A it would have had to ask A for the information. If you ran a proxy on A you could redirect traffic to B and/or C.

You would need to consider how web queries could be directed by A to the appropriate server, B or C. (If B and C are serving the same content then what you have just discovered is a reverse proxy, sometimes known as a load balancer.)

One implementation of such a reverse proxy is [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy)